# filter navigation, site content, etc

Tags: navigation

I am really new to Drupal, so this is a beginners question. 
I need to create a website with a dropdown within the header, where visitors can choose a region (not a language, just a region, like "Europe", "US", ...). The entire page should be filtered according to this selection, so if the visitor chose "US", some parts of the navigation or parts of the content should not be visible.

Is this possible with drupal?

And, more importantly: how would you go about this? The only thing I could think of is create a taxonomy for each "region" and assign content items and navigation items. Is that a good idea? Is there a better way to go?

I'd be thankful for any suggestion. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I'd try [this link](https://www.drupal.org/project/menu_attributes). So install that then apply some classes to the menu items that you can use in JQuery to target the links and have the dropdown links trigger them to show/hide. I'm willing to provide further explanation if there's something you're unclear of. Sadly there is no current module or plugin to provide this functionality that I know of.

Comment: Thank you, but that doesn't really do what I need - the chosen region must be stored through browsing the page, so I guess either in a session or as part of the link. hiding all content / navigation items via jquery seems possible but not really efficient to me.

Comment: OK. You could create a nested menu for each region to be a parent link and use the main menu block on front page then use the menu block module to create the tier two for that menu that would automatically be detected. Of course then if you have pages that go in to more than one region you'd need to use the https://www.drupal.org/project/nodesymlinks module.

Comment: thank you. is there any other way to do this? looks like a lot of duplicated items

Comment: I don't think there's any duplication. that module just provides different url aliases to the content. say you have china/company and usa/company that share a peice of content.